# Issue with WTForms FieldLsit on NDB repeated Structure Property

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, wtforms

I have been using the ferris framework and have some troubles when generating a form for a model. Ferris offers WTForms to render the fields of a NDB Model on a html page.

I have a ndb Model that includes a structured property something like this:

```
class Program(BasicModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    duration = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    contacts = ndb.StructuredProperty(Contact, repeated=True)

class Contact(BasicModel):
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    picture_url = ndb.StringProperty()
    email =  ndb.StringProperty()
```

So since the structured property for contact is repeated I can have many, so to handle this I created a class for the form and set the contacts field as a FieldList:

```
class ProgramForm(model_form(Program)):
    contacts = fields.FieldList(fields.FormField( model_form(Contact) ), min_entries=1)
```

This renders the fields I need on the html page but when posting the form the values always come null. If I append a second set of fields for contacts the second set does send the values but the first remains empty.

I don't know if this is the correct way to habdle repeated structured properties or is there something I am missing.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Daniel and @Chris , were you able to get a solution for this?